# For loop issues for a Markov chain Monte Carlo

Tags: python-2.7, montecarlo, markov-chains, stochastic-process

So here is my next problem. I am trying to to loop through and find out how many of the entries in State_Space have a 1 as their 25th entry yet it keeps telling me that the answer is 0. Here is the code.

```
import random
import numpy

M=numpy.zeros((52),dtype=int)


z=0
State_Space=[]

for i in range(1,100500):
    x=random.randint(1,50)


    T=M.copy()
    if T[x]==1:
        T[x]=0
    if T[x]==0:
        T[x]=1


    if not any(numpy.array_equal(T, X) for X in State_Space):
        if T[x+1]==0 and T[x-1]==0:
            State_Space.append(T)
            if T[25]==1:
                z=z+1
            M=T


    else:
         if T[x+1]==0 and T[x-1]==0:
            M=T


print z
print len(State_Space)
```

Output:

0,
22

Comment: I reread your first question and you said `State_Space` is supposed to be uniformly distributed among all NxN (or in this case 1xN) matrices. Why then do you need `M=T` at the end of the loop.

Comment: This code prints non-zero z for me, but pretty rarely. I suspect that at some point `T[24]` or `T[26]` is set, which means `T[25]` will not be set since it would have a non-zero neighbor. It has to wait for both neighbors to first get unset before `T[25]` can be set, which can be rather unlikely.

Comment: @kalhartt ok sorry I am supposed to be able to code this with a 52X52 matrix and 1X52 row vector. So lets just just talk about the row vector case. We need M=T because we don't want to remember the Markov Chain movement if it isn't in the State Space of vector with no neighboring 1's.

Comment: I see, in any case I believe your code is working as expected. Sometimes I obtain a very high count (>80% of the State_Space), the rest I have a very low or zero count. I think this is just a property of your system.

Comment: you can look at the count for each index by adding this to the end of the script: `for i in range(52): print i, sum(X[i] for X in State_Space)` For me, maybe 1/2~2/3 of the indicies are 0 and the rest are fairly unevenly distributed

Comment: Also, are you allowed to unset a location if it has neighbors set? Should the if statement checks be `T[x]==0 or (T[x+1]==0 and T[x-1]==0)`

Comment: I think you have answered all of our questions.